# Does your arm time travel when moving?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, time-dilation, observers, time-travel

I am no physicist and I wonder, due to Einsteins Special Relativity, does your arm when moving pass through time at a different pace than the rest of your body?

Comment: Hi, despite the downvotes, I personally like this question. You've mentioned that you are no physicist, and it is perfectly acceptable for you not to know the answer to this question, and still be curious. I wonder why some users of this site don't see this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does.  The effect is so minuscule that it will be completely undetectable, but it is theoretically observing time different than your body.

You can use a [Special Relativity calculator](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1224059993) to amuse yourself with this effect.  If your arm is traveling at 1m/s, it experiences a time dilation factor of .00000033%

Comment: that's cool. wouldn't that apply to every molecule in your body as well?

Comment: Technically, yes, though again the effect would be small enough to be measurable.  The one case I am aware of where relativistic effects matter for terrestrial situations came up with atomic clocks: some of our atomic clocks tick slower than others because some are closer to the center of the Earths' gravity well and some are further away.  We actually have correction factors applied when we try to correlate times from different atomic clocks.  Other than that, welcome to the strange world that is physics!

Comment: yes, i think it's funny, that your body is practically build out of millions of tiny time machines.